# Disable buttons only when there is min value of Textbox using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 10 Button with different values in html ..

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="2" id="tblidno2">2</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="3" id="tblidno3">3</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="5" id="tblidno5">5</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="8" id="tblidno8">8</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="3" id="tblidno3">3</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="2" id="tblidno2">2</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="7" id="tblidno7">7</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="4" id="tblidno4">4</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="6" id="tblidno6">6</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="4" id="tblidno4">4</button>
```

and one Input box ,

```
<input type="text" name="given_tblno" id="given_tblno" value="6" />
```

Whenever i change ( using OnChange Event) value in input box of given_tblno i want to disable all buttons with a condition given as,

```
$a=$('#given_tblno').val();
$b=$('#tblidno').val(); // Need to check Each and every Button values using any loop

if($a<$b)
{ 

   //....Here i want Disable buttons when condition is true.... 

}
```

So here in my example when this condition true buttons will be disabled where the values are occurred in buttons 2,3,5,3,2,4,4 ..
Only 8,7,6 values has buttons it should be enabled for click actions.

Using Jquery i wanted to do .

Comment: can you explain it in more detail of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var btns = $('button[name=table_no]');
  $('#given_tblno').on('input', function() {
    var cur = parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
    btns.prop('disabled', function() {
      return parseInt(this.value) < cur;
    });
  }).trigger('input');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="2" id="tblidno2">2</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="3" id="tblidno3">3</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="5" id="tblidno5">5</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="8" id="tblidno8">8</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="3" id="tblidno3">3</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="2" id="tblidno2">2</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="7" id="tblidno7">7</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="4" id="tblidno4">4</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="6" id="tblidno6">6</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="4" id="tblidno4">4</button>
<input type="text" name="given_tblno" id="given_tblno" value="6" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantageof jQuery html() method and JS parseInt method. Just check if button `$(this).html()` is less than the `$('#given_tblno').val()` and if yes, then change `$(this).attr('disabled','disabled')`.

Here is your code:

```
<script>
$("#max_tblno,#given_tblno").change( function() {
    a = parseInt($('#max_tblno').val());
    b = parseInt($('#given_tblno').val());
    if(a<b){
        $(this).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
            $('button').each(
            function(){
                if(parseInt($(this).html())<b){
                    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/piyushkmr/xyL0p6ay/1/

Comment: I have edited my question.. There will not be max_tblno to compare given_tbleno.. When load and change given_tblno should compare with all button values and it should be disable in condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var vals = ['2','3','4','5'];
$("#given_tblno").on('change keyup',function() {
 $a = parseInt($('#max_tblno').val());
 $b = parseInt($('#given_tblno').val());
  if($a<$b){
    $("[value='" + vals.join("'],[value='") + "']").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }else{
     $('button[name="table_no"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h2bpuxxa/)**

Comment: max_tblno will be constant and can't be change you can see that i given as hidden field .So only given_tblno can be change. Kindly update your question

Answer (score 0):

try this out

**html**

```
<head><script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="2" id="tblidno2">2</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="3" id="tblidno3">3</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="5" id="tblidno5">5</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="8" id="tblidno8">8</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="3" id="tblidno3">3</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="2" id="tblidno2">2</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="7" id="tblidno7">7</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="4" id="tblidno4">4</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="6" id="tblidno6">6</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" name="table_no" value="4" id="tblidno4">4</button>
<input type="text" name="given_tblno" id="max_tblno" value="3" />
<input type="text" name="given_tblno" id="given_tblno" value="6" />
```

**jquery**

```
$(function(){
            $('#given_tblno').on('keyup', function() {
                $a=parseInt( $('#max_tblno').val() );
             $b=parseInt( $('#given_tblno').val() );
             if($a<$b)
             {      
                $("button[id^='tblidno']").prop("disabled",true);               
             }
             else
                $("button[id^='tblidno']").prop("disabled",false);
            });
        });
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/r3vkxv11/)

Comment: Did you see the fiddle? i changed your hidden field to text because it you cant change it if it remain hidden.